# Android Implements Interface With TargetApi

Tags: java, android, api, nfc

I've a problem in a Android App, my activity implements `CreateNdefMessageCallback` which is available in `API 14+`.

I annoted the implemented method `public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event)` with `@TargetApi(14)`. It work well on Android 4 devices but produce a crash at loading on devices below Android 4.0 !

The only solution is to create an other `class` for the implementation ? Or it's possible to have a conditional implementation with `@TargetApi` ?

Here is the full exception which don't append if I remove `implements CreateNdefMessageCallback` :

```
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{XXXX/XXXX.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: XXXX.MyActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/XXXX.apk]
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: XXXX.MyActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/XXXX.apk]
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
04-15 11:22:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(3784):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: For the moment, I made an internal Annonymous Inner Type but I listen if you've an other solution for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I made an internal Annonymous Inner Type to solve the issue and a condition to check if the device has an NFC chip or not.

```
mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
   mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(new CreateNdefMessageCallback() {...}, this);
}
```

I also add a second test around this code to check the running version of Android.